# How to hide the Alert Box when the internet connectivity is back.?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a music player app in which I am checking for internet connectivity when the app is running. When the connectivity is gone, I am showing an alert message and stopping the song. In case if the connectivity is back, I am again playing the song without user doing anything in it, but the problem is I am unable to hide the alert when the song is played back again. Here is the code:

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"
CM_EXPORT const CMTime kCMTimeZero;
@interface FirstViewController ()

@end


@implementation FirstViewController
@synthesize  metadatas;
@synthesize toggleButton;
@synthesize slider;
@synthesize mpVolumeView = _mpVolumeView;
@synthesize viewVolume;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    toggleIsOn=TRUE;

    MPVolumeView *volumeView = [[MPVolumeView alloc] initWithFrame:self.viewVolume.bounds] ;

    [self.viewVolume addSubview:volumeView];

    [volumeView sizeToFit];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

-(IBAction)playButtonPressed:(id)sender
{

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setBool:TRUE forKey:@"FirstPlay"];
    [defaults setBool:YES forKey:@"alertShown"];

    if(toggleIsOn){

        toggleIsOn=!toggleIsOn;

        player = nil;
        NSString *stringurl = @"";
        stringurl = @"http://majestic.wavestreamer.com:6221/listen.pls";
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringurl];
        asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:url options:nil];
        playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:asset];
        player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
        player.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;
        [playerItem addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"timedMetadata" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
        [playerItem addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
        [player play];

        NSNotificationCenter *center = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
        [center addObserver:self selector:@selector(audioSessionInterrupted:) name:AVAudioSessionInterruptionNotification object:nil];

        [self.toggleButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"reload.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
        [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: nil];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
    }
    else {

        [self.toggleButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"playMusic.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        self->player.rate=0.0;
        toggleIsOn=!toggleIsOn;



    }


}
- (void)audioSessionInterrupted:(NSNotification *)notification
{

    NSNumber *interruptionType = [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeKey];
    NSNumber *interruptionOption = [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:AVAudioSessionInterruptionOptionKey];

    switch (interruptionType.unsignedIntegerValue) {
        case AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeBegan:{
           // [self.toggleButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"playMusic.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

            // • Audio has stopped, already inactive
            // • Change state of UI, etc., to reflect non-playing state
        } break;
        case AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeEnded:{
            // • Make session active
            // • Update user interface
            // • AVAudioSessionInterruptionOptionShouldResume option
            if (interruptionOption.unsignedIntegerValue == AVAudioSessionInterruptionOptionShouldResume) {
                // Here you should continue playback.
                [player play];
            }
        } break;


        default:
            break;
    }

}


- (void)audioPlayerBeginInterruption:(AVAudioPlayer *)audioPlayer
{
    [player pause];
}
-(void)audioRecorderEndInterruption:(AVAudioRecorder *)audioPlayer
{
    [player play];
}






- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setBool:TRUE forKey:@"alertShown"];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(checkNetworkStatus:) name:kReachabilityChangedNotification object:nil];

    internetReachable = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
    [internetReachable startNotifier];

    // check if a pathway to a random host exists
    hostReachable = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"www.apple.com"];
    [hostReachable startNotifier];


}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
    [self becomeFirstResponder];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
    [self resignFirstResponder];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}


- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object
                        change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {

    [playerItem removeObserver:self forKeyPath:keyPath];


    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"status"]) {
        AVPlayerItem *pItem = (AVPlayerItem *)object;
        if (pItem.status == AVPlayerItemStatusReadyToPlay)
        {
            metadatas.text = @"";
        }
    }
    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"timedMetadata"]) {
        for (AVAssetTrack *track in playerItem.tracks) {
            for (AVPlayerItemTrack *item in player.currentItem.tracks) {
                if ([item.assetTrack.mediaType isEqual:AVMediaTypeAudio]) {
                    NSArray *meta = [playerItem timedMetadata];
                    for (AVMetadataItem *metaItem in meta) {

                        NSString *source = metaItem.stringValue;
                        metadatas.text = source;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    [self.toggleButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:toggleIsOn ? @"playMusic.png" :@"stop.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}


-(IBAction)fbButtonPressed:(id)sender
{

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.facebook.com"];

    if (![[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url])
        NSLog(@"%@%@",@"Failed to open url:",[url description]);
}


-(IBAction)inButtonPressed:(id)sender
{

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.linkedin.com"];

    if (![[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url])
        NSLog(@"%@%@",@"Failed to open url:",[url description]);
}

-(IBAction)tweetButtonPressed:(id)sender
{

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.twitter.com"];

    if (![[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url])
        NSLog(@"%@%@",@"Failed to open url:",[url description]);
}
-(IBAction) sliderChanged:(id)sender
{


}
-(void) checkNetworkStatus:(NSNotification *)notice
{
    // called after network status changes
    NetworkStatus internetStatus = [internetReachable currentReachabilityStatus];
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    switch (internetStatus)
    {
        case NotReachable:
        {
            NSLog(@"The internet is down.");
            NSLog(@"%d",[defaults boolForKey:@"alertShown"]);
            BOOL isAlertShown = [defaults boolForKey:@"alertShown"];
            if(isAlertShown)
           {

               [self showAlert];
           }

            break;
        }
        case ReachableViaWiFi:
        {
            NSLog(@"The internet is working via WIFI.");


            BOOL isFirstTimePlayed = [defaults boolForKey:@"FirstPlay"];
            if(isFirstTimePlayed)
            {
                [self playButtonPressed:nil];

            }


            break;
        }
        case ReachableViaWWAN:
        {
            NSLog(@"The internet is working via WWAN.");
            [self playButtonPressed:nil];

            break;
        }
    }

   }

-(void)showAlert
{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setBool:FALSE forKey:@"alertShown"];

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Alert" message: @"You have lost data connectivity. Please wait while we try to establish the connection again." delegate: nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];



}



- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}




@end
```

Comment: What does this have to do with `iOS`, `iOS7`, the `xcode IDE` and the `xcode 5 IDE`? Tagging your question correctly will get you the best possible answer.

Comment: @Popeye - this is iOS-specific code.

Comment: @Aaron no it's `cocoa-touch`-specific code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your method `showAlert`, you have a reference to the `UIAlertView` object, `alert`. Simply save that reference in a property so that you can access it later.

```
@interface FirstViewController ()
    @property (nonatomic, strong) UIAlertView* internetConnectivityAlertView;
@end

-(void)showAlert
{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setBool:FALSE forKey:@"alertShown"];

    self.internetConnectivityAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert"
                                                                    message:@"You have lost data connectivity. Please wait while we try to establish the connection again."
                                                                   delegate:nil
                                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [self.internetConnectivityAlertView show];
}
```

When you do get internet connectivity, simply call

```
if(self.internetConnectivityAlertView)
{
    [self.internetConnectivityAlertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
    self.internetConnectivityAlertView = nil;
}
```

to dismiss the alert.

See the API Documentation for [UIAlertView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIAlertView/dismissWithClickedButtonIndex%3aanimated%3a).

Comment: great answer. I can't believe how much apple thought of when they wrote the iOS sdk

Comment: What will be the part where I am getting internet connectivity back.?

Comment: Your method `-checkNetworkStatus:` is what you are using to check for connectivity. In the cases `ReachableViaWiFi` and `ReachableViaWWAN`, you know you have connectivity and you can hide the alert.